# Auto delete of file which is the same name

Tags: files, delete

I'm new to ubuntu.

I need some help to auto delete some files inside my home folder.

I run a cron for some SQL backup which create a file into my home folder.

It create thousands of them in a day. The files is usually cron.php, cron.php.1, cron.php.2 and go on.

Is there any auto script that I can write to delete the files?

Thanks
:)

Comment: All files must have different names in the same directory. Give some example file names and your expected file names.

Comment: Why not solve the problem at the root and change or disable the Cron job? What's the point of creating backups that you just end up deleting soon after their creation?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a script that contains this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "How many extra files are there?"
read -r amount
COUNTER=0
while [ $COUNTER -lt "$amount" ]; 
do
    rm cron.php.$COUNTER
    let COUNTER='COUNTER+1'
done
```

This will go through the loop however many times you tell it to (however many extra files there are) and delete each one.

Copy the script into a file (name it whatever you like) with the `.sh` extension and save it to the directory with all of the files that you want to delete. After that, give it permission to execute with `chmod +x filename.sh`. Finally, run it by executing it with the command `./filename.sh`

Comment: so i copy the script on top into a file and save as autodelete.sh and run it inside my crontab -e ? Does this read the folder /home/"myusername"

Comment: Copy the script into a file (name it whatever you like) with the `.sh` extension and save it to the directory with all of the files that you want to delete. After that, give it permission to execute with `chmod +x filename.sh`. Finally, run it by execute it with the command `./filename.sh`